# XSLT nested sort / for-each

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, msxml4

I am trying to figure out the best way to perform a nested for-each & sort.  For example my XSLT below performs the following:

1. Selects a node set.
2. Sorts by Date attribute.
3. Performs position() to pull 4 nodes.

Now, the next part is what I am trying to figure out.  After step 3 I need to sort by the Date attribute again, but this time in asceding order...now that the data set is narrowed down to 4 nodes.  Suggestions?  Thanks for the help!!

---

XSLT:

```
  <xsl:template name="AdmissionsNewsList">
    <ul class="stories-list">
      <xsl:for-each select="AdmissionsSectionFront/TaxonomyNavigation[@Name='AdmissionsNewsList']/Category/Pages/Page">
        <xsl:sort select="@Date" order="descending" />
              <xsl:if test="position() &lt; 5">

                    <!-- NOW THAT THE NODES HAVE BEEN SELECTED, SORTED, AND POSTION LIMIT SET
                         I NEED TO PERFORM ANOTHER SORT BY DATE (ASCENDING ORDER) HERE ON THE NARROWED DOWN DATA SET -->

                            <li>
                              <xsl:choose>
                                  <xsl:when test="normalize-space(@ThumbnailImage)">
                                      <img alt="{@LocalAlternateText}" src="images/{@ThumbnailImage}" />
                                  </xsl:when>
                                  <xsl:otherwise>
                                      <img alt="{@LocalAlternateText}" src="images/News%20Photos/Default.jpg"/>
                                  </xsl:otherwise>
                              </xsl:choose>
                              <div>
                                <h5>
                                  <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
                                </h5>
                                <br/>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="@Abstract"/>
                                <br/><br/>
                                <a href="{@URL}" class="full-story">
                                  <xsl:apply-templates select="Page[@Name='Link']/@Target"/>Full Story
                                </a>
                              </div>
                            </li>

              </xsl:if> 
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
```

---

NOTE:  This had to be in XSLT 1.0 & is using MSXML 4.0 Parser. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately XSL 1.0 doesn't have much support for date data types.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a simple and logical solution. :)

Comment: @Oded: This question is more general and has a good general solution. As for date data type, it seems that the values of the `@Date` attribute (although not shown) are such that simple string sorting works correctly with them (e.g. yyyy/mm/dd)

Comment: @Dimitre - If they are indeed strings of that format, I agree. I have had the misfortune of seeing `dd/MMM/yyyy` and other variations that are not that easy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Instead of**:

```
  <xsl:for-each select=
    "AdmissionsSectionFront/TaxonomyNavigation
                    [@Name='AdmissionsNewsList']/Category/Pages/Page">
    <xsl:sort select="@Date" order="descending" />
          <xsl:if test="position() &lt; 5">
```

**use**:

```
  <xsl:variable name="vNewAdmPages" select=
    "AdmissionsSectionFront/TaxonomyNavigation
                    [@Name='AdmissionsNewsList']/Category/Pages/Page">
  "/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$vNewAdmPages">
    <xsl:sort select="@Date" order="ascending" />
          <xsl:if test="position() > count($vNewAdmPages) -5">
```

**In this way you need a single sort and get directly to the five nodes of interest.**

Comment: +1 Very good answer! First four in descending order should be last four in ascending order.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly & was a great solution!  As the previous commenter stated...very good answer!