# XSLT : Looping from 1 to 60

Tags: xslt

What is the best way to loop in XSLT from 1 to 60?
I research in net, there are some templates to do this, is there any other way for example like a built-in function?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0,

```
<xsl:for-each select="1 to 60">...</xsl:for-each>
```

But I guess that you must be using XSLT 1.0, otherwise you wouldn't be asking.

In XSLT 1.0 you should use recursion: a template that calls itself with a counter that's incremented on each call, and the recursion terminates when the required value is reached.

Alternatively there's a workaround in XSLT 1.0: provided your source document contains at least 60 nodes, you can do

```
<xsl:for-each select="(//node())[60 >= position()]">...</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: How do you access the current value please? (in the three dots in your first snippet) Tried to use `<xsl:variable name="currentCount" select="." />` but with no success.

Comment: Use `position()`

Answer (score 30):

**The problem with simple recursion when processing long sequences is that often the space for the call stack becomes insufficient** and the processing ends due to stack overflow. This typically happens with sequence length >= 1000.

**A general technique to avoid this (implementable with any XSLT processor, even if it doesn't recognize tail-recursion) is DVC (Divide and Conquer) style recursion**.

Here is an example of a transformation that successfully prints the numbers from 1 to 1000000 (1M):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output method="text"/>

     <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:call-template name="displayNumbers">
        <xsl:with-param name="pStart" select="1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pEnd" select="1000000"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template name="displayNumbers">
      <xsl:param name="pStart"/>
      <xsl:param name="pEnd"/>

      <xsl:if test="not($pStart > $pEnd)">
       <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$pStart = $pEnd">
          <xsl:value-of select="$pStart"/>
          <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:variable name="vMid" select=
           "floor(($pStart + $pEnd) div 2)"/>
          <xsl:call-template name="displayNumbers">
           <xsl:with-param name="pStart" select="$pStart"/>
           <xsl:with-param name="pEnd" select="$vMid"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
          <xsl:call-template name="displayNumbers">
           <xsl:with-param name="pStart" select="$vMid+1"/>
           <xsl:with-param name="pEnd" select="$pEnd"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:if>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied on any XML document (not used) this transformation produces the wanted result -- all the numbers from 1 to 1000000.

**You can use/adapt this transformation for any task that needs to "do something N times".**

Comment: You are the XSLT-Guru! I had to downgrade my XSLT 2.0 template and your answer was a life saviour!

Answer (score 2):

### Very simple check inside the foreach-loop

```
<xsl:if test="$maxItems > position()">
    do something
</xsl:if>
```

Based on [Dimitre Novatchev's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3816205/1056159) answer.

**Example:**

```
<xsl:variable name="maxItems" select="10" />
<xsl:variable name="sequence" select="any-sequence"/>

<xsl:for-each select="$sequence">

    <!-- Maybe sort first -->
    <xsl:sort select="@sort-by" order="descending" />

    <!-- where the magic happens -->
    <xsl:if test="$maxItems > position()">
        do something
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 2):

The basic example for V1.0 using recursion would it be like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<Root>
      <!-- Main Call to MyTemplate -->
     <xsl:call-template name="MyTemplate" />
</Root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="MyTemplate">
  <xsl:param name="index" select="1" />
  <xsl:param name="maxValue" select="60" />

  <MyCodeHere>
     <xsl:value-of select="$index"/>
  </MyCodeHere>

  <!-- &lt; represents "<" for html entities -->
  <xsl:if test="$index &lt; $maxValue">
    <xsl:call-template name="MyTemplate">
        <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index + 1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="total" select="$maxValue" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: it would be much simpler to use only one param and count backwards.

Comment: @Alejandro You're right. I changed that validation.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT works based on templates and you'll need a template do run that loop.

You'll need to build a template receiving start and end values and, inside it, make a recursive call computing with start + 1. When $start equals $end, you do return your template, without another call.

In practice: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tiploop/index.html