# XSLT How to do a classic for x to y loop?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to do a classic for i=0 to N loop, how can it be done in xstl 1.0?

thanks.

```
<xsl:for-each select="¿¿¿$i=0..5???">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="$i"/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:for-each>
```

To give an example, I have

```
<foo>
    <bar>Hey!</bar>
</foo>
```

And want an output of

```
Hey!
Hey!
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT : Looping from 1 to 60](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076323/xslt-looping-from-1-to-60)

Comment: The output you have just now added is not clear (or not valid XML).

Comment: Might be you can do away with loops and recursion alltogether. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XSLT is a *functional* programming language and as such it is very different to any procedural languages you already know.

Although `for` loops are possible in XSLT, they do not make use of the inherent strengths of XSLT (and functional programming in general).

`for` loops are routinely misused to address problems that are best solved with a functional approach instead (that is, matching templates). In other words, a loop is not really a "classic" in XSLT.

So, you might have to double back, identify the *problem* you are facing instead of discussion your solution. Then, the XSLT community might be able to suggest a solution that is more functional in nature. It might be that you've fallen victim to the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

---

Now, among the things XSLT is inherently *good* at is recursion. Often, problems that are solved with loops in procedural languages are solved with recursive templates in XSLT.

```
<xsl:template name="recursive-template">
   <xsl:param name="var" select="5"/>
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="$var > 0">
       <xsl:value-of select="$var"/>
       <xsl:call-template name="recursive-template">
         <xsl:with-param name="var" select="$var - 1"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise/>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

To summarize, I suggest you look at "classic" recursion instead of "classic" `for` loops. You find more information about exactly this topic in an IBM article [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tiploop/).

---

**EDIT** as a response to your edited question. If your problem really boils down to outputting text content twice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="text"/>

   <xsl:template match="/foo">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="bar"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="bar"/>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is not feasible of course for a dynamic number of iterations.

Comment: I agree with you but the point is that i need to do the same thing 2 times. Just that, recursion is nice but looks like a bit complicated for the goal. However you gave me an idea with a parametrized template. Be right back!

Comment: Granted, recursion requires a bit of thinking initially, but you've burdened yourself with understanding recursion the moment you decided to use XSLT. If you need something exactly 2 times you might not even need recursion. But is is crucial that you reveal your _problem_ instead of your solution.

Comment: Edited with an example. Almost solved it with a named template but not working so far, need to investigate a little more about the topic. Thanks for help

Comment: Yeah, got it almost as you suggest. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

XSLT 2.0 has `<xsl:for-each select="0 to 5">` but in XSLT 1.0 you can only `for-each` over node sets, not sequences of atomic values.  The easiest way I've found to get around this is to use some kind of sufficiently generic selector expression that will match at least as many nodes as you want iterations, e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/descendant::node()[position() &lt; 7]">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="position() - 1"/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:for-each>
```

or if you don't necessarily know there will be at least 6 nodes in the input document then you can use `document('')` to treat the stylesheet itself as another input document.

```
<xsl:for-each select="document('')/descendant::node()[position() &lt; 7]">
```

In both cases the `for-each` will change the context node, so you'll need to save the outer context in a variable if you need to access it inside the `for-each` body

```
<xsl:variable name="dot" select="." />
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a *named template* with parameters $i and $n; call the template with parameters {$i = 0, $N = 5}; have the template call itself recursively with parameters {$i + 1, $N} until $i > $N.

Example:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<output>
    <!-- stuff before -->
    <xsl:call-template name="block-generator">
        <xsl:with-param name="N" select="5"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <!-- stuff after -->
</output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="block-generator">
    <xsl:param name="N"/>
    <xsl:param name="i" select="0"/>
    <xsl:if test="$N >= $i">
        <!-- generate a block -->
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:value-of select="$i"/>
        </fo:block>     
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="block-generator">
            <xsl:with-param name="N" select="$N"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```