# Iterating For-each loop on the condition provided in the variable in the XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want my for-each loop to work on the condition provide in the variable defined.

If Record_Counter has value 7 in it, then for_each should iterate for 7 times.

Note: I have created the variable Counter to store Record_Counter value.

Please find XSLT code which I tried but it is not giving me desired result.

```
    <xsl:variable name= "Counter" select="Element[1]/@Record_Counter" />
<xsl:for-each select="$Counter">
        <itemGroup ref="ValTechnique">
      <reportItem key="yes">
        <itemValue>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Reporting"/>
        </itemValue>
      </reportItem>
      <reportItem>
        <itemValue>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Valuation"/>
        </itemValue>
      </reportItem>
    </itemGroup>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Which version of XSLT and engine are you using?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including input and the expected output.

Comment: @Sebastien I am using XSLT version 1

Comment: You can use a recursive template, examples here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076323/xslt-looping-from-1-to-60

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 2 and later you can certainly use a `1 to $var` expression e.g. `<xsl:for-each select="1 to xs:integer($Counter)">` but that way inside of the `for-each` the context item is the currently processed integer value so any attempt to select nodes with e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="@Reporting"/>` will not work, you would need to put e.g. `<xsl:variable name="context-node" select="."/>` before the `for-each` and then use e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="$context-node/@Reporting"/>` inside the `for-each`.

That might still not suffice as it is unlikely you want to output the same stuff `$Counter` times but you haven't show your input and wanted output so I can't tell what other changes you need/want.

Comment: Hi, I am using XSLT version 1 how can I achieve the same in version 1?